Benjamin Pierce Types and Programming Languages 6.1.5 Clarification
I'm currently following Pierce's Types and Programming Languages, and I find myself stuck at exercise 6.1.5 (the implementations of removenames? and restorenames?). The rules are as follows:
Gamma |- removenames(v) => rightmost index of v in Gamma
Gamma |- removenames(lambda x : t) => lambda (Gamma, x => removenames(t))
Gamma |- removenames(t_1 t_2) => (Gamma |- removenames(t_1)) (Gamma |- removenames(t_2))
Gamma |- restorenames(nameless_v) => Gamma[nameless_v]
Gamma |- restorenames(lambda . nameless_t) => lambda newvar . (Gamma, newvar |- restorenames(nameless_t))
Gamma |- restorenames(nameless_t1 nameless_t2) => (Gamma |- nameless_t1) (Gamma |- nameless_t2)

Obviously, one of the goals is to show that restorenames (removenames (lambda x : t)) is equal to lambda x : t upto renaming of bound variables. However, proceeding with the structural induction, I get stuck at the last step:
restorenames (removenames (lambda x : t)) is
restorenames (Gamma, x |- lambda . removenames (t)) is
lambda newvar . (Gamma, newvar |- restorenames (Gamma, x |- lambda . removenames (t)))

To proceed, I feel like I should show that the two contexts Gamma, newvar and Gamma, x "behave the same" when the case of the term is an abstraction towards applying the IH. However, I'm not sure if this is the best way to finish the proof.
Any assistance/clarifications would really help!

Show that restorenames commutes with renaming. If we write rename(Γ, Γ', t) to rename the term t with context Γ to context Γ', we want:
rename(Γ, Γ', restorenames(Γ, t)) = restorenames(Γ', t)

Back to your proof, you can do alpha renaming (do double check the side conditions for it!)
  lambda newvar. restorenames((Γ,newvar), removenames(...))
= lambda x. rename((Γ,newvar), (Γ,x), restorenames((Γ,newvar), removenames(...)))  // alpha renaming
= lambda x. restorenames((Γ,x), removenames(...))  // rename commutes with restorenames

now you can apply the induction hypothesis and conclude.
